# Javascript problem with finding html elements from source code of another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble finding individual html elements from the downloaded source code of a selected page. When I use the function `$(data).find('p').length` it returns me the number 2 which is the correct answer, but if I use the function `$(data).find('img').length` it returns me 0 and it should be 1.

```
async function getErrors() {
    await $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com',
            method: 'get'
        })
        .done(async (siteText) => {
            var data = $.parseHTML(siteText);
            console.log(data);
            console.log($(data).find('p').length);
            console.log($(data).find('img').length);
             await axios.get('http://anothersite.com')
            .then((response) => {
                //do something...
            });
        });
}
```

---

Live example:

```js
var siteText = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <style>
        .black{
            background-color: black;
            color: #333131;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Strona Testowa</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Nisi est sit amet facilisis. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Quisque egestas diam in arcu. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. Porttitor eget dolor morbi non. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Nam libero justo laoreet sit. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. Et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. In est ante in nibh mauris. Mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Sed id semper risus in. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Netus et malesuada fames ac. In pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet. Et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190108/ourmid/pngtree-tree-green-plant-photography-png-png-image_305004.jpg" >
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gK8s4LUJ7NE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="black">
        <p class="black">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`;

var data = $.parseHTML(siteText);
console.log(data);
console.log($(data).find('p').length);
console.log($(data).find('img').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you could use the `html()` function on a newly created element to parse your HTML. This way the `find()` function works because it looks for child elements of the new element.

**Detailed explenation:**

HTML parsed by `parseHTML()` and  `html()` will ignore `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

So the parsing returns an array of the nodes in the head and body so the `find()` function runs on every element in that array when wrapped in a jQuery object directly. That's why `find()` can't find the direct children of `<body>`. The `filter()` function works because it filters the array.

By wrapping the result in a new element the find function will work correctly on the full `<body>` content since they are now children of the new element.

```js
var siteText = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        .black{
            background-color: black;
            color: #333131;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Strona Testowa<span class="fa fa-bath"></span></h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Nisi est sit amet facilisis. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Quisque egestas diam in arcu. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. Porttitor eget dolor morbi non. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit. Et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Nam libero justo laoreet sit. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. Et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. In est ante in nibh mauris. Mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Sed id semper risus in. Vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Netus et malesuada fames ac. In pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet. Et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190108/ourmid/pngtree-tree-green-plant-photography-png-png-image_305004.jpg" >
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gK8s4LUJ7NE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="black">
        <p class="black">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`;

var data = $('<div></div>').html(siteText);

$('#target').append(data);

$('#target').find('p').each((i, el) => {
  console.log($(el).css('color'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution works correctly for me and I hope it will help others in the future as well.

Comment: Is there any way to get into the css styles? Because if I do a query ```$(data).find('p').css('color')``` it returns me an empty value.

Comment: @Gandalf69 You can append the nodes to the DOM so the styles will be applied. You can do this without visual changes by appending it do a hidden container. You also need to loop over all the `p` elements since there are multiple. I updated my answer as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have one more question. What if the styles are in another file? For example: ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">``` or ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.coml/css/stylecss">```.

Comment: @Gandalf69 When you have the full url to the css it just works (see my updated example with font awsome). If you have a relative url it doesn't because the path is now incorrect so you would need to change that in a full path yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code with another site and that's working fine. I modified your JS to temporary get rid of async/await:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/2AaFk/1',
    method: 'get'
})
.done((siteText) => {
    console.log(siteText);
    var data = $.parseHTML(siteText);
    //console.log(data);
    console.log($(data).find('h3').length);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Above you have "live example" without async and await and ```console.log($(data).find('img').length); ``` also returns 0.

Comment: i tried with test fiddle and it returned total h3 tags for me.

Comment: you're trying with live site of local site?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jytp0kb8/1/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/lJ7pjpH7IJk8

Comment: The problem is in the html structure. `find()` will not find the direct children of `<head>` and `<body>` because of the return value of the parse function is an array of elements from the head and body .